# Why lamp is not working correctly?

Tags: lighting

I have a study lamp. It works sometimes, and sometimes it does not. I am using 220V power. On the lamp is written `G23 PL-11W 230V/50W`. What do you think what is the problem?

[Link for lamp picture http://www.electromarket220.net.ua/components/com_jshopping/files/img_products/full_3f106e1101c6751d238a8d94d792cf47.JPG](http://www.electromarket220.net.ua/components/com_jshopping/files/img_products/full_3f106e1101c6751d238a8d94d792cf47.JPG)

Comment: If you are sure the light tube is good, other causes, in order of likelihood: failing ballast, faulty switch, faulty cord, faulty internal wiring.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why lamp is not working correctly?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/41644/why-lamp-is-not-working-correctly)

Answer (score 1):

Usually it is the lightbulb itself. It can be that it is nearing its end of life and simly needs to be replaced, or it can be that it just isn't fitted properly. The next best thing but quite unlikely with devices like this, is the powerswitch.